# Can anybody help me in recording iPhone output sound through Audio Unit

Tags: iphone, ios5, core-audio, audiounit

this is my code :
i use this code to record the iPhone output audio by using Audio Unit
then saving the output in output.caf but the output.caf file is empty 
any body have idea about what shall i do ?
the output audio file is empty

this is intializing the audio unit

```
-(void) initializaeOutputUnit
{
    OSStatus status;

    // Describe audio component
    AudioComponentDescription desc;
    desc.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Output;
    desc.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO;
    desc.componentFlags = 0;
    desc.componentFlagsMask = 0;
    desc.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;

    // Get component
    AudioComponent inputComponent = AudioComponentFindNext(NULL, &desc);

    // Get audio units
    status = AudioComponentInstanceNew(inputComponent, &audioUnit);

    // Enable IO for recording
    UInt32 flag = 1;
    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(audioUnit, 
                                  kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO, 
                                  kAudioUnitScope_Input, 
                                  kInputBus,
                                  &flag, 
                                  sizeof(flag));

    // Enable IO for playback
    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(audioUnit, 
                                  kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO, 
                                  kAudioUnitScope_Output, 
                                  kOutputBus,
                                  &flag, 
                                  sizeof(flag));

    // Describe format
    AudioStreamBasicDescription audioFormat={0};
    audioFormat.mSampleRate         = 44100.00;
    audioFormat.mFormatID           = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
    audioFormat.mFormatFlags        = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;
    audioFormat.mFramesPerPacket    = 1;
    audioFormat.mChannelsPerFrame   = 1;
    audioFormat.mBitsPerChannel     = 16;
    audioFormat.mBytesPerPacket     = 2;
    audioFormat.mBytesPerFrame      = 2;

    // Apply format
    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(audioUnit, 
                                  kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, 
                                  kAudioUnitScope_Output, 
                                  kInputBus, 
                                  &audioFormat, 
                                  sizeof(audioFormat));
    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(audioUnit, 
                                  kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, 
                                  kAudioUnitScope_Input, 
                                  kOutputBus, 
                                  &audioFormat, 
                                  sizeof(audioFormat));


    // Set input callback
    AURenderCallbackStruct callbackStruct;
    callbackStruct.inputProc = recordingCallback;
    callbackStruct.inputProcRefCon = self;
    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(audioUnit, 
                                  kAudioOutputUnitProperty_SetInputCallback, 
                                  kAudioUnitScope_Global, 
                                  kInputBus, 
                                  &callbackStruct, 
                                  sizeof(callbackStruct));

    // Set output callback
    callbackStruct.inputProc = playbackCallback;
    callbackStruct.inputProcRefCon = self;
    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(audioUnit, 
                                  kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback, 
                                  kAudioUnitScope_Global, 
                                  kOutputBus,
                                  &callbackStruct, 
                                  sizeof(callbackStruct));

    // Disable buffer allocation for the recorder (optional - do this if we want to pass in our own)
    flag = 0;
    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(audioUnit, 
                                  kAudioUnitProperty_ShouldAllocateBuffer,
                                  kAudioUnitScope_Output, 
                                  kInputBus,
                                  &flag, 
                                  sizeof(flag));


    AudioUnitInitialize(audioUnit);
    AudioOutputUnitStart(audioUnit);


    // On initialise le fichier audio
    NSArray  *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *destinationFilePath = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%@/output.caf", documentsDirectory] autorelease];
    NSLog(@">>> %@", destinationFilePath);
    CFURLRef destinationURL = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)destinationFilePath, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, false);

    OSStatus setupErr = ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL(destinationURL, kAudioFileWAVEType, &audioFormat, NULL, kAudioFileFlags_EraseFile, &effectState.audioFileRef);  
    CFRelease(destinationURL);
    NSAssert(setupErr == noErr, @"Couldn't create file for writing");

    setupErr = ExtAudioFileSetProperty(effectState.audioFileRef, kExtAudioFileProperty_ClientDataFormat, sizeof(AudioStreamBasicDescription), &audioFormat);
    NSAssert(setupErr == noErr, @"Couldn't create file for format");

    setupErr =  ExtAudioFileWriteAsync(effectState.audioFileRef, 0, NULL);
    NSAssert(setupErr == noErr, @"Couldn't initialize write buffers for audio file");

   }
```

the recording call back

```
static OSStatus recordingCallback       (void *                         inRefCon,
                                         AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *      ioActionFlags,
                                         const AudioTimeStamp *            inTimeStamp,
                                         UInt32                            inBusNumber,
                                         UInt32                            inNumberFrames,
                                         AudioBufferList *                 ioData) {
    NSLog(@"callback");
   if (*ioActionFlags == kAudioUnitRenderAction_PostRender&&inBusNumber==0) 
   {
        AudioBufferList *bufferList; // <- Fill this up with buffers (you will want to malloc it, as it's a dynamic-length list)

        EffectState *effectState = (EffectState *)inRefCon;
       AudioUnit rioUnit =[(MixerHostAudio*)inRefCon getAudioUnit];

        OSStatus status;
        NSLog(@"de5eal el call back ");
        // BELOW I GET THE ERROR
        status = AudioUnitRender( rioUnit,     
                                 ioActionFlags, 
                                 inTimeStamp, 
                                 inBusNumber, 
                                 inNumberFrames, 
                                 bufferList);

        if (noErr != status) { NSLog(@"AudioUnitRender error"); return noErr;}

        // Now, we have the samples we just read sitting in buffers in bufferList
        ExtAudioFileWriteAsync(effectState->audioFileRef, inNumberFrames, bufferList);

    }
    return noErr;     
}




// then stop Recording 
- (void) stopRecord
{

    AudioOutputUnitStop(audioUnit);
    AudioUnitUninitialize(audioUnit);
}
```

Comment: It's not sufficient to just say "this is my code" and then post your entire application. That doesn't count as a question.

Comment: make it clear and explain the whole scenario.

Comment: Is there an error coming back from `ExtAudioFileWriteAsync`?

Comment: no their is no error from ExAudioFileWriteAsync
but when i remove 
status = AudioUnitRender( rioUnit,     
                                 ioActionFlags, 
                                 inTimeStamp, 
                                 inBusNumber, 
                                 inNumberFrames, 
                                 bufferList);
and replace buffer list by ioData
and removing the if statement in recording call back 
      
        ExtAudioFileWriteAsync(effectState->audioFileRef, inNumberFrames, ioData);

the output file space is 659KB but it is not working

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In ***initializaeOutputUnit*** you only created your audio file:

```
OSStatus setupErr = ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL(destinationURL, kAudioFileWAVEType, &audioFormat, NULL, kAudioFileFlags_EraseFile, &effectState.audioFileRef);
```

by passing **0** (frames) and **NULL** (audiobuffer) is just for init internal buffers:

```
setupErr =  ExtAudioFileWriteAsync(effectState.audioFileRef, 0, NULL);
```

That's what's going wrong in **recordingCallback**:

1) ioActionFlags are always 0 and inBusNumber are always 1, because thats how you setup your callback (kInputBus = 1):

```
if (*ioActionFlags == kAudioUnitRenderAction_PostRender&&inBusNumber==0)
```

so just remove the if statement.

2) From **AudioUnitRender** you will receive **-50 error**, which is defined in CoreAudioTypes.h as an **kAudio_ParamError** error. This happens by bufferList is not defined and NULL!

> ```
>  OSStatus status; 
>  status = AudioUnitRender(THIS->mAudioUnit,     
>                           ioActionFlags, 
>                           inTimeStamp, 
>                           kInputBus, 
>                           inNumberFrames, 
>                           &bufferList);
>
>  if (noErr != status) {
>       printf("AudioUnitRender error: %ld", status);   
>       return noErr; 
>  }
> ```

You just need to define an valid AudioBuffer and pass it to AudioUnitRender, this is my working RenderCallback:

> ```
>   static OSStatus recordingCallback       (void *                      inRefCon,
>                                            AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *      ioActionFlags,
>                                            const AudioTimeStamp *            inTimeStamp,
>                                            UInt32                            inBusNumber,
>                                            UInt32                            inNumberFrames,
>                                            AudioBufferList *                 ioData)  {
>       double timeInSeconds = inTimeStamp->mSampleTime / kSampleRate;
>       printf("\n%fs inBusNumber: %lu inNumberFrames: %lu ", timeInSeconds, inBusNumber, inNumberFrames);
>       //printAudioUnitRenderActionFlags(ioActionFlags);
>
>       AudioBufferList bufferList;
>
>       SInt16 samples[inNumberFrames]; // A large enough size to not have to worry about buffer overrun
>       memset (&samples, 0, sizeof (samples));
>
>       bufferList.mNumberBuffers = 1;
>       bufferList.mBuffers[0].mData = samples;
>       bufferList.mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = 1;
>       bufferList.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = inNumberFrames*sizeof(SInt16);
>
>       ViewController* THIS = THIS = (__bridge ViewController *)inRefCon;
>
>       OSStatus status;
>       status = AudioUnitRender(THIS->mAudioUnit,     
>                                ioActionFlags, 
>                                inTimeStamp, 
>                                kInputBus, 
>                                inNumberFrames, 
>                                &bufferList);
>
>       if (noErr != status) {
>
>           printf("AudioUnitRender error: %ld", status); 
>           return noErr;
>       }
>
>       // Now, we have the samples we just read sitting in buffers in bufferList
>       ExtAudioFileWriteAsync(THIS->mAudioFileRef, inNumberFrames, &bufferList);
>
>       return noErr;      
>  }
> ```

In **stopRecord** you should close the audio file with **ExtAudioFileDispose**:

> ```
>   - (void)stopRecording:(NSTimer*)theTimer {
>       printf("\nstopRecording\n");
>       AudioOutputUnitStop(mAudioUnit);
>       AudioUnitUninitialize(mAudioUnit);
>
>       OSStatus status = ExtAudioFileDispose(mAudioFileRef);
>       printf("OSStatus(ExtAudioFileDispose): %ld\n", status); 
>  }
> ```

Full source code: http://pastebin.com/92Fyjaye

Answer (score 3):

The RemoteIO Audio Unit does not record audio output, only input from the microphone.  The output is not connected to the mic input.

If you use RemoteIO for playing audio, you can copy the copy the same buffers you feed the output callback for playing audio to a file writer as well.  But that's only for raw audio content you play via RemoteIO.

Comment: i write my code using those links about audio unit
[Blog] ( http://atastypixel.com/blog/using-remoteio-audio-unit/ )

[Question] ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118429/how-to-record-sound-produced-by-mixer-unit-output-ios-core-audio-audio-graph )

that why i use Remote I/o to record audio output

Comment: RemoteIO does not record audio output.  Read Apple's official Audio Unit documentation instead.

Comment: so do you have any documentation that help me to record the iPhone audio output ???

Comment: @hotpaw2 I have found an alternative, but it records both outer and inner sound as well.